# Windows Service watcher Not reading the xml files properly, you have to restart the service to read

Tags: html, xml, vb.net

I have created A windows service. The service has 3FileSystemWatcher. Its job is when the XML files arrive in each of the three Folders, the service takes the files process them and puts the data in SQL tables. When I start the service it works fine, but after a while when i put files in the folders the service doesn't take them, I have to restart the service to work properly? I will attach the APP.config here to show you how it looks like. if anyone have had a similar problem please help me.

```
<add key="Thread.Sleep" value="7000" />
<add key="SleepOnCreated" value="1" />
<add key="Buffer" value="32768" />
<add key="VerifyTimeOut" value="600000" />
<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
```

---

Try ' Za prviot XML= users, role members, SiteBazi
            fsw_Users_RoleMembers_SiteBazi.Path = CType(conf.GetValue("folderpathPrimeni1", GetType(System.String)), String)
            fsw_Users_RoleMembers_SiteBazi.Filter = "*.xml"
            fsw_Users_RoleMembers_SiteBazi.IncludeSubdirectories = False
            fsw_Users_RoleMembers_SiteBazi.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
            fsw_Users_RoleMembers_SiteBazi.InternalBufferSize = CInt(CType(conf.GetValue("Buffer", GetType(System.String)), String)) '
            AddHandler fsw_Users_RoleMembers_SiteBazi.Created, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf File_Created1)
            fsw_Users_RoleMembers_SiteBazi.EnableRaisingEvents = True

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Neuspesna notifikacija za XML users_roleMembers_SiteBazi, filter " & ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Try 'Za vtoriot = site privilegii vo Bazi
        fsw_SitePrivilegii_voBazi.Path = CType(conf.GetValue("folderpathPrimeni2", GetType(System.String)), String)
        fsw_SitePrivilegii_voBazi.Filter = "*.xml"
        fsw_SitePrivilegii_voBazi.IncludeSubdirectories = False
        fsw_SitePrivilegii_voBazi.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
        fsw_SitePrivilegii_voBazi.InternalBufferSize = CInt(CType(conf.GetValue("Buffer", GetType(System.String)), String)) '
        AddHandler fsw_SitePrivilegii_voBazi.Created, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf File_Created2)
        fsw_SitePrivilegii_voBazi.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Neuspesna notifikacija za XML SitePrivilegii vo Baza, filter " & ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Try 'Za vtoriot = Privilegii po bazi
        fsw_Privilegi_Po_Bazi.Path = CType(conf.GetValue("folderpathPrimeni3", GetType(System.String)), String)
        fsw_Privilegi_Po_Bazi.Filter = "*.xml"
        fsw_Privilegi_Po_Bazi.IncludeSubdirectories = False
        fsw_Privilegi_Po_Bazi.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
        fsw_Privilegi_Po_Bazi.InternalBufferSize = CInt(CType(conf.GetValue("Buffer", GetType(System.String)), String)) '
        AddHandler fsw_Privilegi_Po_Bazi.Created, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf File_Created3)
        fsw_Privilegi_Po_Bazi.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Neuspesna notifikacija za XML Privilegii po bazi, filter " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Show the code in the FileSystemWatcher. The app.config doesn't tell us anything

Comment: I thought that the config was the problem, because when i restart the service it workls. So I do all the things on the event File CREATED... the code looks like this



Dim wrk As New Worker
        wrk.arg = e
        'single thread
        Dim Pauza As Int32 = CType(conf.GetValue("SleepOnCreated", GetType(System.String)), String)
        Thread.Sleep(Pauza)
        wrk.Process_Users_roleMembers_SiteBazi(e.FullPath, e.Name) 'This is the class were I do all the reading and insert in the datavase

Comment: And  at the whatcher I have this:

Comment: Please don't put code in a comment.  It is totally unreadable.  Please edit your question and add the code there.